The LaTeX Companion, Third Edition. Did I just buy a photocopied version of the book?
I just bought The LaTeX Companion, Third Edition, on Amazon, and I have the impression that I bought a photocopied version of the book, and not an original version.
On all the pages, I have little black dots.
Here's a photo of part of page 18 of the first book.
https://mega.nz/file/npxD0BoQ#KpNPDKwjicF5XFvPU15zvu52pbCEhfaiWcg5gth4qOI

What does your page 18 look like?
Alex

Usually counterfeit editions would be black and white where the original was color, so I think this probably isn’t a counterfeit, but I can’t say for certain. (The counterfeit problem is, on the other hand, one more reason to prefer buying books from anywhere but Amazon).

Hardcover with ribbon? Has it been bought directly from  Amazon or from the marketplace?

The highest quality way to print books is use offset printing. Sometimes, typically after a book has ben in print for a long time, a publisher will use digital printing, which  is cheaper and similar to a laser printer, and can be good quality and in colour. But sometimes the quality is not nearly so good, like on a laser writer.  Perhaps that is what you have.

The seller is Amazon.com.ca ULC, which is the official name of Amazon Canada. Hardcover but without ribbon.

x-post https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/12712/the-latex-companion-3rd-edition-qualite-de-limpression-livre-photocopie
